# How do you find a minimum of a function with these tools?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, optimization, computer-science, computational-complexity

Let's say I can define a group $G$ acting on a set of combinatorial objects $X$ and I have a function $f: X \to \Bbb{N}$ that I want to find a minimum of in $X$.

Is there a polynomial time algorithm using thes above tools to find a minimum of $X$ starting with an input that is a maximum of $X$?  I mean the running time is $O(P(n))$ where $P$ is some polynomial and $n = f(x_0)$ is a maximum?

If the answer is no or idk, is there if we add more requirements to $G$ and $f$?

Comment: Gradient Descent can do that. It can find an approximation to a local minimum of f, given a start-value for X and a "step-size" constant (constant too small => slow convergence, constant too big => no convergence). If you're interested in this kind of stuff, this online-course might be for you: https://www.coursera.org/course/ml Unfortunately i don't remember the details so i can't give a complete answer.